# PHP - mPDF set resolution

Tags: php, mpdf

Is it possible to set resolution of PDF file using mPDF class. I'm trying to save image which is mainly black but with some thin white lines, and I can't see those white lines in PDF so I assume I have to increase resolution.

EDIT:

This is my code. First I save my page as html:

```
<?php 
    $fileID = uniqid();
    $_SESSION['fileID'] = $fileID;
    file_put_contents("$fileID.html", ob_get_contents());
    header("Location: createPDF.php"); 
?>
```

then I convert this page (which is full of svg images) into pdf:

```
<?php

    include 'MPDF57/mpdf.php';
    session_start();

    $fileID = $_SESSION['fileID'];
    $yourHtml = "$fileID.html";
    $mpdf=new mPDF('', '', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents('main.css'),1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents($yourHtml)); 
    $mpdf->Output();
    unlink($yourHtml);
    unset($_SESSION['fileID']);
    header("index.php");
    exit;

?>
```

Now I need to know if there is any way to change resolution of pdf file.

Comment: How is the image created? CSS? jpg?

Comment: Image is pulled from server, it's svg, When I print this image to printer, then everything is ok, so I think there is problem with resolution

Comment: I edited my question. I posted code which I made, I can't try to solve this problem if I don't know the command for this, I searched internet and couldn't find answer so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue before i solve it by modifying the variables in `config.php`

```
$this->img_dpi = 96;    // Default dpi to output images if size not defined
```

I added a large image and modified the dpi, it worked.

Comment: Tried this and I still get the same problem, only when I increase dpi my image is smaller

Comment: I'm trying to save this image: http://screencloud.net/v/2xVB but when I open pdf I only get black triangle

Comment: I fixed it by converting my image from svg to jpg, now everything is ok. Thank you for your tip

Comment: my approach was, 1- change the image size to a larger size. 2- increase the dpi. and it works.